# Multiple aliases for one column

Tags: mysql

I know I can assign a temporary alias to a column. For example:

```
select foo, length(foo) as bar from my_table
```

And I know that I can use these aliases to get their values:

```
select foo, length(foo) as bar from my_table order by bar asc
```

But sometimes I want to make the results of my queries more readable, and when there is a space within a alias, I cannot use its value in the rest of the query:

```
select foo, length(foo) as "Foo's length" from my_table order by ? asc
```

Is there a way to define one alias for the query and one alias, that will be seen in the results?

Comment: Spaces, apostrophes, etc. - just a bad idea

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't this work:

```
select foo, length(foo) as `Foo's length`
from my_table
order by `Foo's length` asc;
```

Or, use the old-style `order by` with a column reference:

```
select foo, length(foo) as `Foo's length`
from my_table
order by 2 asc;
```

Or, repeat the expression:

```
select foo, length(foo) as `Foo's length`
from my_table
order by length(foo) asc;
```

Comment: The column reference in form of a number and a repeated expression is new for me, but backticks... (facepalm). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
select foo, length(foo) as "Foo's length" from my_table order by 2 asc
```

In `order by 2` 2 is the column index

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that MySQL is a bit schizophrenic about what a double quote means. Sometimes it means a string literal, sometimes it means a column alias.

When you write the query as you do;

```
select foo, length(foo) as "Foo's length" 
from my_table order by "Foo's length" asc
```

...it will actually create a column alias called `Foo's length`, but order by *the string literal* `Foo's length`. Since the string literal is the same for all rows, the ordering will be pseudo random.

What you need to do with MySQL is to quote your aliases consistently with backtick, and things will work well;

```
select foo, length(foo) as `Foo's length` 
from my_table order by `Foo's length` asc
```

[An SQLfiddle showing the difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dfdf/1).